# Can I use child table primary key in parent table?

Tags: sql

I have a situation

My games table have child table teams
after, game completion I have to declare winnner
can I use like this?

my games table

| id | game | winner |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | game 1 | team_1_id |
| 2 | game 2 | team_10_id |

another work around in teams table

| id | game_id | name | is_winner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | team_1 | true |
| 2 | 1 | team_2 | false |

is first option is valid?

I need suggestion, what is the good practice

Comment: MySQL or Postgres? Please do not add tags for database not involved

Comment: If you want to know what is good practise, read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms first.

Answer (score 0):

First option is valid. You will just have a bi-directional relationship. It makes sense here. Each game will have one winner. And winner can be stored with game table. We avoid one more table.

Comment: 'Each game will have one winner.' - really , no draws?

Comment: in that case also i prefer to have game table to store winner data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).